# Converting Django models queryset into a numpy matrix

Tags: python, django, numpy, pandas

I want to pull out a set of fields for objects in a Django queryset and convert them into a matrix with the fields as columns for some computation. I've gotten to the point of :

`qs = models.Devices.objects.all()`

`params = qs.values('b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8')`

which returns a list of dictionaries ordered by object.

I want to know if there's a good way to convert these into rows of a numpy matrix and also if there is a way to keep an index of where these values are held in the db?

I want to do some calculations (sometimes different ones depending on the parameter type) and then eventually use the resultant vectors to populate/overwrite an existing column in the db such that the ordering is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You could

1. Use the `values_list()` method to get a list of lists. Include the `id` in the values.
2. Use list comprehension on the result of the query to remove the ids from the `params` and generate a list of `ids`.
3. Use the `params` as the parameter for `numpy.matrix()`.
4. Perform operations on the matrix.
5. Iterate over the ids and save the values from each row of the matrix to the corresponding object.

   ```
   import numpy as np
   qs = models.Devices.objects.all()
   params = qs.values_list('id', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8')
   ids = [arr.pop(0) for arr in params]
   matrix = np.matrix(params)
   # perform operations here
   for index, id in enumerate(ids):
       row = matrix[index].flat
       obj = qs.get(id=id)
       obj.b1 = row.next()
       obj.b2 = row.next()
       obj.b3 = row.next()
       obj.b4 = row.next()
       obj.b5 = row.next()
       obj.b6 = row.next()
       obj.b7 = row.next()
       obj.save()
   ```